# Error Code: 1136. Not sure why i am getting this error

Tags: mysql

I have counted and recounted many times to make sure that the data being inserted has the same amount as the columns and it still is giving me the

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

```
INSERT INTO WebsiteBooking 
                (WBCustomerName, WBEmail, WBHomeAddress, 
                WBPhoneNumber, WBWorkshop, WBWorkshopDate, 
                WBDateMade) 
        VALUES ('George Frank', 'Frank.George@gmail.com', '5 Dayboro Road, Queensland, 4521', 
                '0411255635', '1', '2021-07-09' , 
                '2021-03-17' );
```

I have no clue as to why it is happening. I saw another question similar to this one and it said it had something to do with auto increment and i have removed the auto increment and also another one that it could be the trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auto_insert_to_Customer_Booking;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER auto_insert_to_Customer_Booking
    AFTER INSERT ON WebsiteBooking 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (new.WBCustomerName, new.WBEmail, new.WBHomeAddress, new.WBPhoneNumber);
    INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (new.WBCustomerName, new.WBWorkshop, new.WBWorkshopDate, new.WBDateMade);
END$$
DELIMITER ; 

CREATE TABLE WebsiteBooking(
    WBBookingID INT,
    WBCustomerName VARCHAR(50) ,
    WBEmail VARCHAR(50),
    WBHomeAddress VARCHAR(50),
    WBPhoneNumber VARCHAR(10),
    WBWorkshop VARCHAR(50),
    WBWorkshopDate DATE,
    WBDateMade DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (WBBookingID)
);
```

Comment: Specify columns list in both INSERT in the trigger.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken because WBBookingID INT isn't an auto incremented value you need to add that to the insert list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check after changing the WBBookingID column into AUTO_INCREMENT.

ALTER TABLE `WebsiteBooking` MODIFY COLUMN `WBBookingID` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above because WBBookingID INT isn't an auto incremented value you need to add that to your insert list, or make WBBookingID an auto incremented value.

```
INSERT INTO WebsiteBooking 
    (WBBookingID, WBCustomerName, WBEmail, WBHomeAddress, 
     WBPhoneNumber, WBWorkshop, WBWorkshopDate, 
     WBDateMade) 
VALUES (1, 'George Frank', 'Frank.George@gmail.com'
    ,'5 Dayboro Road, Queensland, 4521', '0411255635', '1'
    ,'2021-07-09' , '2021-03-17' );
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE WebsiteBooking (
    WBBookingID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,WBCustomerName VARCHAR(50)
    ,WBEmail VARCHAR(50)
    ,WBHomeAddress VARCHAR(50)
    ,WBPhoneNumber VARCHAR(10)
    ,WBWorkshop VARCHAR(50)
    ,WBWorkshopDate DATE
    ,WBDateMade DATE
    ,PRIMARY KEY (WBBookingID)
);
```